# Installing mysql client on EC2 via CloudFormation

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

To install MySQL client on my EC2 instance I do the following:

```
# Update all packages
sudo yum update

# Install mysql client 
sudo yum install mysql
```

I would like to know how can I provision that using CloudFormation when I create my EC2 instance?

Is there any samples which I can refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a simple script on an EC2 instance provisioned using CloudFormation, you use the [`UserData`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata) property of the [`AWS::EC2::Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) resource.

Example:

[image: Launch Stack]

```
Description: Run a bash script using the UserData property.
Mappings:
  # amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20161221-x86_64-gp2
  RegionMap:
    us-east-1:
      "64": "ami-9be6f38c"
Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [ RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", 64]
      InstanceType: m3.medium
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            # Update all packages
            yum -y update
            # Install mysql client 
            yum -y install mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share also on top of the answer above.

I later found out my EC2 is deployed via EB and UserData does not seem to work.

In that case, I have to use .ebextension's [container_commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands).

So posting it here hopefully it will help someone as well:

```
files:

  "/usr/local/bin/eb_mysql.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |        
        #!/bin/bash

        yum -y update
        yum -y install mysql          

container_commands:
  040_install_mysql_client:
    command: "chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/eb_mysql.sh && /usr/local/bin/eb_mysql.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL Client:

1. sudo yum install -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
2. sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
3. sudo yum install -y mysql-community-client